# Sqlalchemy filter by single value in a list that is in a row

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Basically, I have an SQLAlchemy model in which categories are stored as a json list. The list might look like `[1, 6, 7]`. I need to know how (and if) I can somehow filter by a value in this list. Something like `Object.query.filter_by(tag in json.loads(category).all()` (`json.loads()` would return a python list here, not a dict).

````py
def sort_objects(mode, return_size, **kwargs):
    if "page" in kwargs.keys():
        page = kwargs['page']
    else: page = 1
    if "tag" in kwargs.keys():
        tag = kwargs['tag']
    else: tag = 0

    if mode.lower() == "new":
        q = Object.query.filter(tag in json.loads(category)).\
        order_by(Object.uploaded_utc.desc()).paginate(page, return_size, False).items```
````

Comment: What data-type does that column have in Postgres? Also JSON?

Comment: @exhuma the data type is a string, because it's just a JSON string. I know postgres has some other data types that better fit a list, but that doesn't help me solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `?` operator (or `@>` for integer values) on JSONB columns in PostgreSQL for this. See [the JSON page for a detailed reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html)

As you mention "tags", I will assume the values in the array are strings, so we can go with the `?` operator.

There are a few things that are to be known to solve this puzzle:

### The values need to be in the postgres JSONB type

As mentioned in the comment, the values are currently not stored as `JSONB`, but as `TEXT` so we need to convert these. This can be done using `sqlalchemy.cast`. We also need to pull in the JSONB type from `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` for that cast.

### We need to call a non-standard operator

The way this is done is by calling `.op()` on a column of the SQLAlchemy model. This will return a new "callable" which takes the "right-hand-side" of that operator (where "left-hand-side" is the table-column). So for example, if we had a column named `mycolumn` and an operator called `yoink` and we want to do `mycolumn yoink 10` we would need to write the following:

```
    Table.mycolumn.op("yoink")(10)
    \------------------------/\--/
          mycolumn yoink       10
```

All this can then be combined to the following filter-expression (using "needle" as the tag value we search for:

```
session.query(MyTable).filter(
    cast(MyTable.myjsoncolumn, JSON).op("?")(needle)
)
```

### For your code

Given your question, my guess is that the query is something like this for *your* code:

```
session.query(MyTable).filter(
    cast(Object.category, JSON).op("?")(tag)
)
```

### Note on TEXT vs JSONB

If your "category" column contains JSON data it would make a lot of sense to use the JSONB type internally instead of plain text. It will allow you to do more fancy queries if needed (like the one from this question) without the need for casting.

### Fully running example

Here is an example which creates a simple table with a JSON column, then inserts some dummy data and queries it at the end.

I ran this using an isolated docker container for postgres using:

```
docker run --rm --name pgdb -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foobar -p 5432:5432 postgres
```

```
from json import dumps

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, cast, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class SomeClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "some_table"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(String())


engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:foobar@127.0.0.2/postgres")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

# Ensure we are working with an empty table on repeating calls
session.query(SomeClass).delete()
session.add_all(
    [
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-10", "tag-20", "tag-30"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-10", "tag-20", "tag-30"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-10", "tag-20", "tag-30"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-10", "tag-20", "tag-30"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-1", "tag-2", "tag-3"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-2", "tag-3", "tag-4"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-3", "tag-1", "tag-2"])),
        SomeClass(data=dumps(["tag-2", "tag-3", "tag-1"])),
    ]
)
session.commit()

print("--- Unfiltered:")
q = session.query(SomeClass)
for row in q:
    print(row, row.data)

print("--- Filtered:")
q = session.query(SomeClass).filter(
    cast(SomeClass.data, JSONB).op("?")('tag-2')
)
for row in q:
    print(row, row.data)
```

Comment: I keep getting an operator error saying "?" is not a valid operator.

Comment: Changed the column type to JSONB, but I keep getting an error saying `HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: What's your PG version? Also, can you add your DDL to the question?

Comment: I actually just figured it out. I needed to force tag to string when doing the query, and needed to use the `@>` operator.